# Test REST service based on request.user

Tags: django, rest, curl, postman

I build SPA on Django and I want to GET and POST JSON data based on `request.user`. 
Something like this:

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return {
        "data": [
            i.get_json() for i in Customer.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.pk)]
    }
```

But I confuse, how it possible to put my user in request by REST service, like "Postman" or "Curl".
Postman has "Authorization" field, so I put login and password into it and my headers update with:
`Authorization        Basic YWdlbmN5X3NwYUBtYWlsLnJ1OjExMTEx`
And I test it with curl:
`curl -u myuser:11111 http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/myurl/`
But user still - AnonymousUser
It could work with angular later, but I don't understand how I can test it now.

Comment: If you are using Django rest framework, please post your settings for it and the view class

Comment: @dkarchmer no, I build it without REST Framework, I found solutions, just misunderstand a bit

Comment: You should avoid reinventing the wheel. Look into Django rest framework

Comment: @dkarchmer yes, I now, I should. But now it is too late for this project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I need to login with my user first and take `sessionid` from Cookie, then put `sessionid` in request.
Postman has nice extension named "Postman Interceptor", it put all session from browser into request authomaticly.